# Why do C++ std container iterators ignore some template parameters of their underlying container?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, std

Here is a specific example. In the code below, I would have expected a compilation error like "cannot assign value of type std::map<**int, int, cmp**>::iterator to variable of type std::map<**int, int**>::iterator". However, I am able to compile the code without any issues (g++ C++20 Wall). Thanks for help.

```cpp
#include <map>

struct cmp {
    bool operator()(const int a, const int b) const { return a > b; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::map<int, int> m1;
    std::map<int, int>::iterator m1_it = m1.begin();

    std::map<int, int, cmp> m2;
    std::map<int, int, cmp>::iterator m2_it = m2.begin();

    // Why do these work?
    m1_it = m2.begin();
    m2_it = m1.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The iterator doesn't care how the tree is built, it just traverses it.

Comment: Why do you expect that changing the type of the comparator would change the type of an iterator?

Comment: To put it another way: once the tree has been built, the ordering is fully determined by the tree's structure.

Comment: Well, I think it's unexpected behaviour. What a map actually represents (i.e. a tree) and whether the comparator has an impact on it should not matter for the compiler. By that logic, it should also be valid to assign an iterator of a float map to an iterator of an int map - this is invalid as expected.

Comment: iterators abstract a pointer mechanism.  So essentially you are pointing to a map of integers, just like you can point to an array of integers.  The order of the elements in the containers doesn't change how you point to the container.

Comment: This is interesting and subtle, though. They could easily have defined the integrators inside the templated container class, in which case you would have two distinct iterator types. I wonder if the standard actually specifies that the Iterator don’t care about cmp. I’m a bit surprised; had you asked I would have thought you’d know what sorting you had based on the iterator type alone.

Comment: Generally the standard is abstract about how an iterator is implemented. For most containers, it just names what type of iterator it needs to be (forward, random access, etc), but not implementation. Most likely GCC doesn't care for the `Compare` template param since the iterator doesn't need this for traversal (tree nodes don't use compare, and traversal is just over the ordered nodes). Not including the `Compare` parameter also has the added benefit that there is less type duplication -- thus less rtti, debugging symbols, etc

Comment: The standard doesn't promise one way or the other about lots of things. A different implementation might reject that program, and both are complying with the standard.  There is a school of thought which thinks it [*should*](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2911.pdf) in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard sets few [constraints on iterator types](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#container.reqmts-6) and just imposes some behaviours.

In particular:

- they don't have to be in `namespace std`. So `T*` might be a valid iterator for `std::vector<T>`.
- they don't have to have same template parameters than their container. For above example `T*` might be an iterator for `std::vector<T, Allocator>` for any `Allocator`.

Whereas, indeed, it is less type safe, less template parameter allows less instantiations (faster compilation, less generated similar code, ...).

Notice that your code might not compile for compilers/libraries which uses all template parameters for their iterators.

Answer (score 1):

One practical reason is that this might lead to smaller executables. Your two map types can share one iterator type, so all the iterator functions are also shared.